# ios center multiple uilabel in a view

Tags: ios, xamarin, view, label

I have to center 3 labels horizontally on the same line. So :

The first label can be resize (programmatically)
The second and third have fixed width.

I want to put ALL 3, in the same line and center all 3.

Have I to put all 3 in a view ? Or stackView?

Thanks for help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add Hosrizontally center to container constraint to all three labels.

Comment: Add the width constraints for your two labels, add a horizontal center constraint for all three labels, and make sure to add a vertical spacing constraint for all three labels to make them stack, and spacing(leading and trailing) constraints if you do not want them to stack.